Set default PST file to MS365 account profile configured in Outlook
I am using Profman dll to create new Outlook profile for M365 user account. The Outlook client version installed is 2016. I have used RPC-over-HTTP or MAPI-over-HTTP to connect to an M365 mailbox as mentioned here. It allows me to create a new profile successfully but it don't add Outlook Data file to profile.
I want set the default Outlook Data file for the newly created profile. The example provided here allows to add a PST but its not connecting to M365 mailbox. How can I set the PST file as default and M365 account data gets sync with PST file?

Exchange (Office 365) accounts use OST stores for local storage, not PST. You need to add an Exchange account and ensure it is cached. Outlook will create the OST file.

Could you please share the example for it?

Do you mean how to add a new Exchange account? See https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman_examples.htm#ROH_Profile_Outlook2016

I have added new Exchange account with above example. Now I want to enable 'Cached Exchange Mode' programmatically.

You need to set PR_PROFILE_CONFIG_FLAGS property on the Exchange service profile section and make sure the CONFIG_OST_CACHE_PRIVATE bit is set. You can also set CONFIG_OST_CACHE_PUBLIC and CONFIG_OST_CACHE_DELEGATE.
